# Optimizing queries in a has_many_through association with three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to avoid n+1 query

I'm working on a web based double entry accounting application that has the following basic models;

```
ruby
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :splits
  has_many :entries, through: :splits
end

class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :splits, -> {order(:account_id)}, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :entry
  attribute :amount, :integer
  attribute :reconciled
end

class Split < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entry, inverse_of: :splits
  belongs_to :account
  attribute :debit, :integer
  attribute :credit, :integer
  attribute :transfer, :string
end
```

This is a fairly classic Accounting model, at least it is patterned after GnuCash, but it leads to somewhat complex queries. (From ancient history this is pretty much a 3rd normal form structure!)

First `Account` is a hierarchal tree structure (an Account belongs to a parent (except ROOT) and my have many children, children may also have many children, which I call a family). Most of these relations are covered in the Account model and optimized as much as you can a recursive structure.

An Account has many Entries(transactions) and entries must have at least two Splits that the sum of the Amount attribute(or Debits/Credits) must equal 0.

The primary use of this structure is to produce Ledgers, which is just a list of `Entries` and their associated `Splits` usually filtered by a date range. This is fairly simple if the account has no Family/Children

```
ruby
# self = a single Account
entries = self.entries.where(post_date:@bom..@eom).includes(:splits).order(:post_date,:numb)
```

It get more complex if you want a ledger of an account that has many children (I want a Ledger of all `Current Assets`)

```
ruby
def self.scoped_acct_range(family,range)
  # family is a single account_id or array of account_ids 
  Entry.where(post_date:range).joins(:splits).
  where(splits: {account_id:family}).
  order(:post_date,:numb).distinct
end
```

While this works, I guess I have an n+1 query because if I use `includes instead of joins` I won't get all the splits for an Entry, only those in the family - I want all splits. That means it reloads(queries) the splits in the view. Also distinct is needed because a split could reference an account multiple time.

My question is there a better way to handle this three model query?

I threw together a few hacks, one going backwards from splits:

```
ruby
def self.scoped_split_acct_range(family,range)
  # family is a single account_id or array of account_ids
  # get filtered Entry ids
  entry_ids = Split.where(account_id:family).
  joins(:entry).
  where(entries:{post_date:range}).
  pluck(:entry_id).uniq
  # use ids to get entries and eager loaded splits

  Entry.where(id:eids).includes(:splits).order(:post_date,:numb)
end
```

This also works and by the ms reported in log, may even be faster. Normal use of either would be looking at 50 or so Entries for a month, but then you can filter a years worth of transactions - but you get what you asked for. For normal use, an ledger for a month is about 70ms, Even a quarter is around 100ms.

I've used a few attributes in both Splits and Accounts that got rid a few view level queries. Transfer is basically concatenated Account names going up the tree.

Again, just looking to see if I'm missing something and there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nested select is the proper option IMO.

You can optimize your code with the nested select to use the following:

```
entry_ids = Entry.where(post_date: range)
  .joins(:splits)
  .where(post_date: range, splits: { account_id: family })
  .select('entries.id')
  .distinct

Entry.where(id: entry_ids).includes(:splits).order(:post_date,:numb)
```

This will generate a single SQL statement with a nested select, instead of having 2 SQL queries: 1 to get the Entry ids and pass it to Rails and 1 other query to select entries based on those ids.

---

The following gem, developed by an ex-colleague, can help you deal with this kind of stuff: https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc

In your case, it would enable you to do the following:

```
Entry.where_assoc_exists(:splits, account_id: 123)
  .where(post_date: range)
  .includes(:splits)
  .order(:post_date, :numb)
```

Which does the same thing as I suggested but behind the scene.

Comment: I believe in order to enforce a single query you would need to add `references(:splits)` to this lines `Entry.where(id: entry_ids).includes(:splits).order(:post_date,:numb)`. `includes` does not always generate 1 query it is deterministic about it. If the association is not mentioned in a condition of the query (in hash syntax) then includes will issue 2 queries one for the primary data and one for the associated data (OUTER JOINish), if the association is mentioned then this will be 1 query (INNER JOIN). To enforce a single query and a join you can use `references(association_name)`

Comment: Thank you. Guess I've never had a use for nested selects before. I've seen them, but when pluck came out I got on that bandwagon. I think I have other pluck stuff around that I need to fix.